# Finite dimensional Lie algebra with non-degenerate invariant bilinear forms $\Omega_{ab}$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, invariant-theory, root-systems

Firstly, my apology to MO experts that I am in a more science/physics background (a PhD). So please feel free refine/modify/comment my language if I have different math accents than yours. From reading this [MO post: complete-classification-of-six-dimensional-non-semi-simple-lie-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152952/complete-classification-of-six-dimensional-non-semi-simple-lie-algebra), I just learned many useful comments and papers in the literature.

From what I had learned in the Reference of this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152952/complete-classification-of-six-dimensional-non-semi-simple-lie-algebra), we can (strictly?) organize the classes of finite dimensional Lie algebra by:

**I.** semi-simple. (Killing form is non-degenerate)

**II.** non-semi-simple (Killing form is degenerate):

$\bullet$ non-solvable.

$\bullet$ solvable and nilpotent.

$\bullet$ solvable but not nilpotent.

---

**QUESTION**: Here I am simply interested in focusing on:

"What are the list of **6 dimensional Lie algebra** and **8 dimensional Lie algebra**, which allow **symmetric non-degenerate invariant bilinear forms $\Omega_{ab}$**?"
(hopefully the list can be as complete as possible, but a partial list is welcome.)
If there is a list of corresponding $\Omega_{ab}$ metric, it will be the best.

---

I am mostly interested in **non-semi-simple case**, and in **real** Lie algebra more than the **complex** Lie algebra (of course, if providing examples of **complex** Lie algebra will also be nice).

**eg:** So far I know only one example in 6-dimension is [the nilpotent Lie algebra $A_{6,3}$ with symmetric nondegenerate $\Omega_{ab}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152952/):

The algebra is 
$$
[e_1,e_2]=e_6,\;\;[e_1,e_3]=e_4,\;\;[e_2,e_3]=e_5,
$$
with other commutators are zeros. One can find the nondegenerate $\Omega_{ab}$ to be:
$$
\Omega_{ab}={\begin{pmatrix} 
q_1 & 0&0&0 &q_2&0 \\
0& q_3 & 0& -q_2&0 &0\\
0& 0& q_4 & 0& 0& q_2\\
0&  -q_2 & 0& 0& 0 &0\\
q_2 &0& 0& 0& 0 &0\\
0& 0& q_2 & 0& 0 &0
\end{pmatrix}}
$$

What are other examples in **6 dimensional Lie algebra** and **8 dimensional Lie algebra**? (for those semi-simple Lie algebra, I suppose we can use Killing form = $\Omega_{ab}=-{f_{ak}}^l{f_{bl}}^k$. What are the complete lists of semi-simple and non-semi-simple ones of 6 and 8 dimensions?)

Papers/Ref are mostly welcome. (This question is well-motivated by constructing a type of [Wess-Zumino-Witten model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wess%E2%80%93Zumino%E2%80%93Witten_model)). Thank you for the concern.

Comment: A comment on the first part of your question: Every finite dimensional real Lie algebra is a semi-direct product of a solvable and a semi-simple Lie algebra (Levi-Decomposition), so the classifiction of finite dimensional Lie algebras splits up in the (distinct) two cases of solvable and semi-simple lie algebras. In the class of the solvable lie algebras, you have the proper tower of classes: solvable contains nilpotent contains abelian.

Comment: @archipelago, thanks so much for the comment. I recall that learning this sometime ago reading Lie algebra.

Comment: @archipelago: the classification does not split: you still have to classify the actions of semisimple Lie algebras on solvable Lie algebras. Also if you have a given semidirect product, whether it has a nondegenerate invariant bilinear form does not reduce to looking the radical and the semisimple factor. For instance, $sl_2(C)\ltimes C^2$ has no invariant quadratic form, while $sl_2(C)\ltimes C^3$ (adjoint representation) has one.

Comment: @Dietrich: I think you mean *indecomposable*. Otherwise you also have the abelian one, as well as the direct product of the indecomposable 5-dimensional one by the 1-dimensional one.

Comment: @Dietrich, Thanks for comments. In 6-dimension, it should be the $A_{6,3}$ example I gave. Are there others 6-dimension (any, both semi-simple and non-semi-simple) with a _symmetric_ non-degenerate invariant bilinear form?

Comment: @Yves, Thanks a lot. I believe you are saying : $⊕^6 A_{1}$ and $A_{5,3}⊕A_1$. Are there more?

Comment: @mystery: for every Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, if the dual $\mathfrak{g}^*$ is viewed as an abelian Lie algebra with the coadjoint representation $ad^*(x)(L)(y)=-L([x,y])$, the semidirect product $\mathfrak{g}\ltimes\mathfrak{g}^*$ has a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form (simply given by duality). This provides quite many examples, although not all...

Comment: @Dear all commenters: another refined question is posted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/153013/the-existence-of-a-finite-dimensional-lie-algebra-with-a-given-symmetric-invaria; would you mind shed some light on how to find the Lie algebra? Many thanks.

Comment: Dear Dietrich: what do you mean by this paper: (M. Goze, P. Piu, 1991)??? title and journal?

Answer (score 6):

There are several classification lists of solvable and nilpotent *quadratic Lie algebras*, i.e., having a symmetric, invariant non-degenerate bilinear form. For the classification of nilpotent quadratic Lie algebras of dimension $n\le 7$ over the field of real and complex numbers, see

Piu P., Goze M., Gruppi e Algebre di Lie, appunti per un seminario, Universita degli studi di Cagliari, Dipartimento di Mathematica, 1991.

Gr. Tsagas and P. Nerantzi: Symmetric invariant non-degenerate bilinear forms on nilpotent Lie algebras - see [here](http://www.mathem.pub.ro/proc/bsgp-03/K03-TSNE.PDF).

It turns out, that in dimension $6$ there is just one indecomposable nilpotent quadratic algebra, and a decomposable arising from the $5$-dimensional and $1$-dimensional quadratic algebra. In dimension $8$ there are many (two-step nilpotent) examples, but I think, no complete classification.

For the classification of solvable ones in dimension $n\le 6$ see

Tien Dat Pham, Anh vu Le, Minh thanh Duong: [Solvable quadratic Lie algebras in low dimension](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4787%E2%80%8E).

In general, see double extension construction and work by Medina and Revoy, Favre and Santaroubane, and many others.

Comment: Thanks Dietrich for the nice answer. This is what I looked for. Sorry I am a physicist with poor math. Could you fill me in: you state **"solvable and nilpotent quadratic Lie algebras" <-> "having a symmetric, invariant non-degenerate bilinear form"**. Is this an iff statement? But how about simple Lie algebra (not solvable) which _DOES_ provide non-degenerate bilinear form(i.e.(Killing)?

Comment: @ Dietrich, what is the equivalent statement for **"having a symmetric, invariant non-degenerate bilinear form"** for Lie algebra? Is that "solvable and nilpotent quadratic Lie algebras" or something more than that? Can it be **real** or **complex** Lie algebra? Many thanks.

Comment: @mystery, it is more than that. You said that you are mostly interested in the non-semisimple case, and then it is natural to consider the solvable (reps. nilpotent) case.